# Access global IP via local network

Tags: ip-address

How can I access my global ip address 84.151.219.x in my local network? If I would enter 84.151.219.x in my browser I'll go to my routers configuration page..

Comment: I deleted my answer as this is more network/technical related and not programming related. It should be moved to serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may well find that from inside your network you can not do this.

On larger routers what you are trying to do is sometimes called tromboneing (Think of the shape of a trombone's slide), and is prevented by something called [Split Horizons](http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/split-horizon) (Which can normally be turned off in those devices).

In smaller, home type equipment, the router normally keeps outside out and inside in.

The only posibility is a proxy server outside your network to bounce the traffic through in order to hit your router from outside and have your traffic processed through the external access rules.